# NodeJS: Have a setInterval loop only while another variable is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, setinterval

```
function setNormal() {
    console.log(1)
}

function setAlert() {
    console.log(2)
}

function alertFunction() {
    alertVar = setInterval(alertFunc, 600);
}

function alertFunc() {
    setAlert()
    setTimeout(setNormal, 300)
}
alertFunction()
});
```

how do I make the function alertFunction() run only when (for example) var loop = 1 and then stop when var loop = 0?

(this is my first post to stackoverflow so sorry if I did this wrong)

Comment: I'd revisit your basic JavaScript book, and take a look at the `if` statement. To stop an interval, do a Google for "clear javascript interval".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use setTimeout with a condition.

```js
var x = 1;

setTimeout(function foo(){
  // this is a named function expression, foo name only exists inside itself
  if(x!==0){
     // do some code
     console.log("Hello");
     setTimeout(foo,1000);
  }
},1000);

setTimeout(function(){
   // change x after 3 seconds
   x = 0;
},3000);
```

You can also use clear interval to do the same thing

```js
var x = 1;

var interval = setInterval(function (){
  if(x!==0){
     // do some code
     console.log("Hello");
  }else{
     clearInterval(interval)
  }
},1000);

setTimeout(function(){
   // change x after 3 seconds
   x = 0;
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Like It:-

```
var alertVar;
function alertFunction() {
    alertVar = setInterval(alertFunc, 600);
}
function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(alertVar);
}
if(lool=1){
   alertFunction();
}
if(lool=0){
   myStopFunction();
}
```